# Create similar to fb:tag

Tags: javascript, html, xml, facebook, xml-namespaces

I would like to create something similar to fb: tag.

For example if you put fb:comments in your code it would display your comments from Facebook.

Ofcourse you need to include the Facebook xmlns in your HTML head.

How can I create my own tags to perform for example encryption?

For example: `<myEncrypt:key>encrypted word</myEncrypt:key>`

Is that possible? I think it is. Can someone give me some directions on how to achive that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to insert elements with custom namespaces into your HTML? (at run-time in the browser?) Or maybe also how to process them (e.g. perform encryption) where they occur? (again, at run-time in the browser)

Comment: Both. I think that adding custom namespaces is not that hard. The hard part is to perform the encryption server side and return the result in html AT RUN TIME! (suppose that just a simple encryption algorithm will be used). Introducing that I will be able to remove probably SSL and introduce that as an alternative!

Comment: So you're wanting to insert custom tags into your HTML in the browser, send them to the server, and do processing on them. You're asking a big question, and pretty vague. What parts of the technology stack are already decided? E.g. what server-side framework are you going to use? If you're trying to invent an alternative to SSL, why are you asking us to help reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually done by javascript (if you are talking about puting fb:... in html). All that you need to do is parse the DOM tree on load of document for particular tag/prefix and process as needed. You can use jQuery or dojo etc for complex queries. Same concept used in dojo for widgets but with custom attribute on tag.

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="button">
```

Comment: Hm.. Thanks. Do you believe that I can easily do encryption / decryption with something like that?

Comment: Who are you trying to hide the data from, and how secure do you want it to be?  The above answer basically says you'd be doing encryption/decryption on the client, which means you'll be sending plaintext and/or the encryption keys to the client.