# Facebook tag (fb:...)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create similar to fb:tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447377/create-similar-to-fbtag)

In addition to my question:

[Create similar to fb:tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447377/create-similar-to-fbtag)

I would like to ask if someone knows how did Facebook create fb:tags using xmlns.

Just technologies and some short explanation.

I might find the answers that I am looking for the other question as well!

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. What problems did you expect them to encounter?

Comment: I want to create a tag <my_tag:decrypt>encryptedword</my_tag:decrypt> and if anyone use this tag I will decrypt the word and present it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

xmlns is used just to make html valid xhtml, the functionality wont work just by adding fb:.. imported javascript is the on which process these tags

Comment: Is it possible to do encryption server side using Javascript? Only if I parse with Javascript and POST to server with Ajax and jQuery?

Comment: Yes, if you want it to be done at serverside you can use custom JSP tags (if you are using java)

Comment: I am using ruby.. But I would like to process tags inside canvas or other websites.Just like facebook. Is that possible?

Comment: yes.. then only option is javascript. you can post content to your site and get it decrypted and show